# change firstviewcontroller button title from different view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, ios7.1

When user select pick location button then segue triggered to next UIViewController  TableView
In TableView if user select didSelectRow, the title of the select pick locationbutton title  had to change to the user selected address

please help me how to overcome

Comment: So you have an UITableView who send you to the next UIViewController when you Select a Row ? And the Title of the next UIVIewController isn't good ?

Comment: not title of the view i want title of the button in firstviewcontroller

Comment: So you want to send the button title of the first view to the second view ?

Comment: no didselectrow value ie some string to button text title

Comment: You can use protocol for this. create protocol of second class. From didselectrow method, trigger protocol method with passing select row text(for button title), whose definition is in class first. now  you can change button title.

Comment: surjeet if you dont mine can u write little bit code am new to iphone development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In your next view controller, add a property:

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *formerViewController;
and in your first view controller, add this:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
YourNextViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
nextViewController.formerViewController = self;
}


@class formerViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your next view controller, add a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *formerViewController;
```

and in your first view controller, add this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    YourNextViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    nextViewController.formerViewController = self;
}
```

So you can call your first view controller in the next view controller through `formerViewController` property.

And of course, there are some much more complicated ways, such as KVO and NotificationCenter.

Comment: and firstviewcontroller is in storyboard second is in xib when i try to init xib class in my storyboard it is showing error